# How to get a previous value of each row of the same table?

Tags: oracle

I have table:

```
| CLIENT_ID | TYPE_SERVICE | VALUE | IN_DATE  |
| --------- | ------------ | ----- | -------- |
| 2         | i            | HH    | 22.01    |
| 1         | ii           | EE    | 21.01    |
| 1         | i            | CC    | 15.01    |
| 2         | i            | GG    | 13.01    |
| 1         | i            | BB    | 07.01    |
| 2         | i            | FF    | 05.01    |
| 1         | ii           | DD    | 02.01    |
| 1         | i            | AA    | 02.01    |
```

After ORDER BY  it looks like:

```
| CLIENT_ID | TYPE_SERVICE | VALUE | IN_DATE  |
| --------- | ------------ | ----- | -------- |
| 2         | i            | HH    | 22.01    |
| 2         | i            | GG    | 13.01    |
| 2         | i            | FF    | 05.01    |
| 1         | ii           | EE    | 21.01    |
| 1         | ii           | DD    | 02.01    |
| 1         | i            | CC    | 15.01    |
| 1         | i            | BB    | 07.01    |
| 1         | i            | AA    | 02.01    |
```

And I need to get for all rows their old value:

```
| CLIENT_ID | TYPE_SERVICE | VALUE | OLD_VALUE | IN_DATE  |
| --------- | ------------ | ----- | --------- | -------- |
| 2         | i            | HH    | GG        | 22.01    |
| 2         | i            | GG    | FF        | 13.01    |
| 2         | i            | FF    |           | 05.01    |
| 1         | ii           | EE    | DD        | 21.01    |
| 1         | ii           | DD    |           | 02.01    |
| 1         | i            | CC    | BB        | 15.01    |
| 1         | i            | BB    | AA        | 07.01    |
| 1         | i            | AA    |           | 02.01    |
```

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID INT, TYPE_SERVICE VARCHAR2(2), VALUE VARCHAR2(2), IN_DATE DATE );

insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (2, 'i', 'HH', TO_DATE('2201', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (2, 'i', 'GG', TO_DATE('1301', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (2, 'i', 'FF', TO_DATE('0501', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (1, 'ii', 'EE', TO_DATE('2101', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (1, 'ii', 'DD', TO_DATE('0201', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (1, 'i', 'CC', TO_DATE('1501', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (1, 'i', 'BB', TO_DATE('0701', 'DDMM'));
insert into CLIENTS (CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE, VALUE, IN_DATE) values (1, 'i', 'AA', TO_DATE('0201', 'DDMM'));
```

Pay attention that this table does not have a PRIMARY KEY!

**How to get a previous value of each row of the same table?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the LEAD window function here -

```
SELECT C.*, LEAD(VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID, TYPE_SERVICE ORDER BY CLIENT_ID DESC, TYPE_SERVICE DESC, IN_DATE DESC)
FROM CLIENTS C
ORDER BY CLIENT_ID DESC, TYPE_SERVICE DESC, IN_DATE DESC;
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f06a1887bffcc61d1374fa52b8fbfe6f).